# Uniformly compact on a set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am wondering if anyone can provide me with the definition of a uniformly compact mapping on a set. The mapping is defined as a ``point-to-set'' map. I cannot seem to find any literature discussing the concept of uniform compactness. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would probably help if you could supply the reference where the term "uniformly compact" is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of searching turns up a couple of definitions. The most common, however, seems to be this one.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $F:X\to\wp(Y)$; such a function is called a *point-to-set map* from $X$ to $Y$. $F$ is *uniformly compact near* a point $x\in X$ if $x$ has an open nbhd $V$ such that $\operatorname{cl}_Y\bigcup_{y\in V}F(y)$ is compact. $F$ is *uniformly compact* if $F$ is uniformly compact near $x$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: It seems I did not search hard enough, thanks!

Comment: @Erik: You’re welcome!